# Trigger excel solver from vb.net web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, solver

Using vb.net, visual studio 2013 and excel 2010.

I have a web page and when a button is clicked values are passed from the page to excel ( a presaved formatted copy).  I then want to run the solver add in (which I have also preconfigured).  I have been searching for a while now and cannot find a way of doing this.

The below is the code I use to open the excel application

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\RTO.xlsx")
xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets("Optimiser")
```

Another curious problem that may be related is when I open excel from the web page the solver addin is enabled in excels options but does not appear in the data ribbon tab.  If I disable and enable it in the options it comes back.

UPDATE

I tried the following code

```
xlApp.Run("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\SOLVER\solver.xlam!Auto_Open")
```

But it errors with the following

> Additional information: Cannot run the macro 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\SOLVER\solver.xlam!Auto_Open'.
>   The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be
>   disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and thinking about my problem, I came up with the following.

I cannot find any help about triggering solver from within my vb.net code but you can trigger a macro.

First I added the following code which loaded solver.xlam into excel once it had launched.

```
xlWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\SOLVER\solver.xlam")
```

I then created a macro in excel to launch solver.  Once done I added the following line of code into my web page.  Runsolver is the name of the macro.

```
xlApp.Run("RunSolver")
```

Hope this helps someone else down the line

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so

1) a website that populates excel with data and then streams the excel to the client. 
2) the client then fill out or manipulates stuff in the excel.
3) Then clicks a button to solve and perhaps submit the excel...(where you are stuck)

Step 3 could be accomplished with a small 'one click application ' aka 'clickonce', whereas the application is online and served from your site. You could take one cell of your excel and have it open IE and point to the installer, and even pass a parameters (be sure to allow params to pass in the app) as to where the excel was located. Then the app could interop with the excel and do its stuff, perhaps even deliver data back to the server.